# Access both table data through relation

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables with a `Many-to-Many` relation. So I created a third table:

professor  < -- > turma   | Pivot: professor_turma

Here is my model's code:

```
class Professor extends Model
{
    public function turmas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Turma', 'professor_turma',                'cod_professor', 'cod_turma');
    }
}

class Turma extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'turma';

    public function professores(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Professor');
    }
}
```

my Professor's Controller:(The one my `route` redirects to)

```
class ProfessorController extends Controller
{
    public function getProfessorList()
    {
        return View::make('professor', [
            'professor' => Professor::orderBy('nome','asc')->get()
        ]);
    }
}
```

In my view, I'm trying to access the data of both tables (Professor, Turma).

```
<ul class="prof-list col-md-4">
   @foreach($professor as $prof)        
      <li>
         <h3 data-id="{{ $prof->cod_professor }}" class="prof-name">{{ $prof->cod_professor }} - {{ $prof->nome }} 
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check_prof" />
         </h3>

      <ul class="list-disc">
         @foreach($prof->turmas as $disc)
            <li data-dia="{{ $disc->dia_semana }}" data-time="{{ $disc->hr_inicio}}" data-id="{{ $disc->cod_disciplina }}">{{ $disc->nome_disciplina }}                 </li>
        @endforeach
     </ul>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

I'd like to know how could I access `Turma`'s data without the second `@foreach`  without using `$disc`. Is it possible? How ?

`@foreach($prof as $disc)`

Why I can't do something like:

```
@for($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++)
   {{ $professor->turmas[$i]->dia_semana }}
@endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to eager load the "turmas" instead of lazy loading.
This will also make your code more effecient since it won't query the DB for each "professor" row.
See: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

This should fix the problem:

```
Professor::with('turmas')->orderBy('nome','asc')->get()
```